# How do I properly size and position dojo widgets?

Tags: css, dojo

I've spent some number of weeks trying to properly size, position, and otherwise style input fields for a form using dojo widgets. After a lot of research on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, including many pages of documentation on the dojotoolkit.org site, I have not seen a way to reliably size and position each field.

I want to input a date, a start time, and an end time all on the same line. To do this, I'd like to use dijit/form/DateTextBox, dijit/form/ValidationTextBox, and dijit/form/Select.

For example, I have this section of HTML:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="form-id" widgetid="form" lang="en">
<div>
  <span id="day-id-1" style="width: 12px; visibility: hidden;">1</span>
  <input id="date-id" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" required="true" style="width: 150px;">
  <input id="start-hr-id" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp:\'[0-9]{1,2}\', invalidMessage:\'Must be one or two digits.\'" value="7" style="width: 30px; text-align: right;">:
  <input id="start-min-id" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp:\'[0-9]{2}\', invalidMessage:\'Must be two digits.\'" value="00" style="width: 30px; text-align: center;">
  <select id="start-mer-id" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" style="width: 32px;">
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="PM" selected="selected">PM</option>
  </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input id="end-hr-id" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp:\'[0-9]{1,2}\', invalidMessage:\'Must be one or two digits.\'" value="8" style="width: 30px; text-align: right;">:
  <input id="end-min-id" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="regExp:\'[0-9]{2}\', invalidMessage:\'Must be two digits.\'" value="30" style="width: 30px; text-align: center;">
  <select id="end-mer-id" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" style="width: 32px;">
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="PM" selected="selected">PM</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to move the CSS into a .css file and link to it. But, I can't, because that does not appear to work with these widgets.

Also, the text-align does not show up correctly. The numbers 7, 8, 00, and 30 are left aligned in their boxes. I'd like first two to be right aligned and the other two to be centered.

When I look at this in Chrome (on Windows 10) and examine it in Developer Tools, I see that the Computed formatting for text-align on  has "right" crossed out for element.style and replaced with "start input, textarea, select, button" from *user agent stylesheet.* Setting the style to "!important" on the element doesn't override this.

Is there a reliable way to set the style for these fields without putting it into the HTML (or fixing it with JavaScript)? How would you suggest fixing text-align?

Thank you for your guidance!

---UPDATE---

In response to MiBrock, here's how the CSS is specified:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/css/CookieNotice.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/css/greenmaking.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Test RSS-Feed" href="<?php echo WB_URL; ?>/modules/news/rss.php?page_id=12" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm working within an environment that uses WebsiteBaker, an open source PHP framework. The references to TEMPLATE_DIR go to the templates subdirectory in the framework, and most of the CSS comes from that framework. The greenmaking.css has my custom CSS, and the googleapis is for standard font characters provided by Google.

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Hi Rich! How do you initialize your CSS - File? We have multiple CSS Files integrated and all works fine. Like : <link type="text/css" href="http://YourServer/YourDirectory/YourCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: MiBrock, thanks for your question. Please see the update to the question.